# Add pagination in wordpress admin in my own customized plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to display pagination in one of my page of plugin,created by me.. i tried lots of examples but no one is working..

i'll be vary thankful if anyone can give answer...

note: i want pagination in back end(in admin) not in front end

Comment: You could extend the WP_List_Table but I don't know how much is that recommended, due to the possible change of the class itself. It's possible to store a copy in your plugin subfolders, include it, so it will always stay the same. http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem in different way. And solution is [here](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/06/22/how-to-add-pagination-into-list-of-records-or-wordpress-plugin/)

I use second option which has title "How To Add Pagination To WordPress Plugin?".
This gives almost same pagination functionality as WordPress has.

Do not forget to download that "pagination.class.php" file, put it in your plugin folder and give appropriate path while including this file in your plugin.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/165483) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 42):

Easy Steps :

```
$pagenum = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? absint( $_GET['pagenum'] ) : 1;
```

Find total numbers of records

```
$limit = 10; // number of rows in page
$offset = ( $pagenum - 1 ) * $limit;
$total = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table_name" );
$num_of_pages = ceil( $total / $limit );
```

Give limit:

```
$entries = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table_name LIMIT $offset, $limit" );
```

Add this code where you want pagination:

```
$page_links = paginate_links( array(
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'pagenum', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __( '&laquo;', 'text-domain' ),
    'next_text' => __( '&raquo;', 'text-domain' ),
    'total' => $num_of_pages,
    'current' => $pagenum
) );

if ( $page_links ) {
    echo '<div class="tablenav"><div class="tablenav-pages" style="margin: 1em 0">' . $page_links . '</div></div>';
}
```

Comment: Don't take what's in the `$_GET` var directly as that's a security vulnerability. Use the `filter_input` method, like this: `$pageNum = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pageNum') ? absint(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pageNum')) : 1;`

Comment: @Stan he doesn't do that, actually `absint($v)` is a "`Synonym of abs( intval( $foo ) )`" - after using intval() on it it is safe... **Sidenote:** Even faster is `absint((int)$_GET['pagenum'])`

Answer (score 7):

**Generic pagination function.**

This example looks like this on a large db:

<kbd><<</kbd> <kbd>Previous</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> ... <kbd>822</kbd> <kbd>823</kbd> <kbd>Next</kbd> <kbd>>></kbd>

or

<kbd><<</kbd> <kbd>Previous</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> ... <kbd>815</kbd> <kbd>816</kbd> <kbd>817</kbd> <kbd>818</kbd> <kbd>819</kbd> <kbd>820</kbd> <kbd>821</kbd> <kbd>822</kbd> <kbd>823</kbd> <kbd>Next</kbd> <kbd>>></kbd>

or

<kbd><<</kbd> <kbd>Previous</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> ... <kbd>812</kbd> <kbd>813</kbd> <kbd>814</kbd> <kbd>815</kbd> <kbd>816</kbd> <kbd>817</kbd> <kbd>818</kbd> ... <kbd>822</kbd> <kbd>823</kbd> <kbd>Next</kbd> <kbd>>></kbd>

enjoy...

```
<?php 
/*Max Number of results to show*/
$max = 10;
/*Get the current page eg index.php?pg=4*/

if(isset($_GET['pg'])){
    $p = (int) $_GET['pg'];
}else{
    $p = 1;
}

$limit = ($p - 1) * $max;
$prev = $p - 1;
$next = $p + 1;
$limits = (int)($p - 1) * $max;

//This is the query to get the current dataset (change api to suit)
$result = mysqli_query($res, 'SELECT * from yourtable limit '.$limits.','.$max.'');

//Get total records from db (change api to suit)
$totalres = mysqli_result($res, mysqli_query($res, 'SELECT COUNT(id) AS tot FROM yourtable"'),0);

//devide it with the max value & round it up
$totalposts = ceil($totalres / $max);
$lpm1 = $totalposts - 1;

echo pagination($totalposts, $p, $lpm1, $prev, $next);

//The function
function pagination($totalposts, $p, $lpm1, $prev, $next){
    $adjacents = 3;
    if($totalposts > 1)
    {
        $pagination .= "<center><div>";
        //previous button
        if ($p > 1)
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"?pg=$prev\"><< Previous</a> ";
        else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\"><< Previous</span> ";
        if ($totalposts < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)){
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $totalposts; $counter++){
                if ($counter == $p)
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                $pagination.= " <a href=\"?pg=$counter\">$counter</a> ";}
        }elseif($totalposts > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)){
            if($p < 1 + ($adjacents * 2)){
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++){
                    if ($counter == $p)
                    $pagination.= " <span class=\"current\">$counter</span> ";
                    else
                    $pagination.= " <a href=\"?pg=$counter\">$counter</a> ";
                }
                $pagination.= " ... ";
                $pagination.= " <a href=\"?pg=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a> ";
                $pagination.= " <a href=\"?pg=$totalposts\">$totalposts</a> ";
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($totalposts - ($adjacents * 2) > $p && $p > ($adjacents * 2)){
                $pagination.= " <a href=\"?pg=1\">1</a> ";
                $pagination.= " <a href=\"?pg=2\">2</a> ";
                $pagination.= " ... ";
                for ($counter = $p - $adjacents; $counter <= $p + $adjacents; $counter++){
                    if ($counter == $p)
                    $pagination.= " <span class=\"current\">$counter</span> ";
                    else
                    $pagination.= " <a href=\"?pg=$counter\">$counter</a> ";
                }
                $pagination.= " ... ";
                $pagination.= " <a href=\"?pg=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a> ";
                $pagination.= " <a href=\"?pg=$totalposts\">$totalposts</a> ";
            }else{
                $pagination.= " <a href=\"?pg=1\">1</a> ";
                $pagination.= " <a href=\"?pg=2\">2</a> ";
                $pagination.= " ... ";
                for ($counter = $totalposts - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $totalposts; $counter++){
                    if ($counter == $p)
                    $pagination.= " <span class=\"current\">$counter</span> ";
                    else
                    $pagination.= " <a href=\"?pg=$counter\">$counter</a> ";
                }
            }
        }
        if ($p < $counter - 1)
        $pagination.= " <a href=\"?pg=$next\">Next >></a>";
        else
        $pagination.= " <span class=\"disabled\">Next >></span>";
        $pagination.= "</center>\n";
    }
    return $pagination;
}
?>
```