# php- Paginate data from array

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress, pagination

I am making a WordPress plugin to integrate with our library system. I am trying to create a page with a search form to search the database. I have created an API on our library server (it is on our local network) so the site can interface with our library back end.

I am trying to paginate results pulled from the API, the data is in json. I have created the following code to get the json from the API and turn it into a PHP array, it does not implement search, yet:

```
add_shortcode("book_search_form", "book_search_form");
function book_search_form() {

    $api_url = get_option('api_url');
    $api_key = get_option('api_key');
    $data = file_get_contents("$api_url/book/index.php/name/awesome/$api_key");

    $data = (array)json_decode($data, true);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data);
echo '</pre>';


}
```

here is the output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(22) {
    ["barcode"]=>
    string(12) "000015427928"
    ["name"]=>
    string(74) "Janice VanCleave's 201 awesome, magical, bizarre & incredible experiments."
    ["author"]=>
    string(12) "Janice Pratt"
    ["author_last"]=>
    string(9) "VanCleave"
    ["publisher"]=>
    string(11) "Wiley: 1994"
    ["year_pub"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["edition"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["genre"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["checkout"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["series"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["callnum"]=>
    string(5) "507.8"
    ["fiction"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["in_house"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["timestamp"]=>
    string(10) "1374711656"
    ["outto"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["duedate"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ISBN"]=>
    string(10) "0585339376"
    ["media_type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["print"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["BOXID"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["uid"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["printed"]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(22) {
    ["barcode"]=>
    string(12) "000015429634"
    ["name"]=>
    string(50) "Our Awesome Earth: Its Mysteries and Its Splendors"
    ["author"]=>
    string(4) "Paul"
    ["author_last"]=>
    string(6) "Martin"
    ["publisher"]=>
    string(35) "Natl Geographic Society: March 1994"
    ["year_pub"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["edition"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["genre"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["checkout"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["series"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["callnum"]=>
    string(3) "050"
    ["fiction"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["in_house"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["timestamp"]=>
    string(10) "1382550052"
    ["outto"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["duedate"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ISBN"]=>
    string(10) "0870445456"
    ["media_type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["print"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["BOXID"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["uid"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["printed"]=>
    string(5) "false"
  }
}
```

I am trying to create pagination, because some of the queries contain 50 or more books. I have done this before with mysql but I cannot figure out how to do it with an array.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want a pagination to my options page of wordpress plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379792/i-want-a-pagination-to-my-options-page-of-wordpress-plugin)

Comment: Do you need to implement pagination on the array because the API you reference doesn't offer an offset and length to be passed in with the search term? If so, would you be looking to execute the search query on every request and always return a subset of the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following is the prototype of the code you would use for pagination ,just alter it to get the desired results.

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && isset($_GET['paramsfordataonnextpage']))
{
$page=$_GET['page'];   // get the value of the page from your url
$recordsPerPage=10; // number of records you want on your page
$array=//from your service
$index=($page*$recordsPerPage)-1;
$recordsToBeDisplayed = array_slice($array,$index,$recordsPerPage);// this array contains all the records you would want to display on a page;



    $total_pages=ceil(count($array)/$recordsPerPage);
    }
else { 

//use default values

}

<html>...<body><div id="records"><!-- use the array created above to display records -->
    </div>
<div id="pagination">
for($j=1;$j<=$total_pages;$j++){
                    if($j==$page)
                   {?>

                   <li style="display: inline;"><a href="/yourpaginationpage.php?paramsfordataonnextpage=&page=<?=$j?>"><u><?=$j?></u></a></li>
                   <?}else{?>
                        <li style="display: inline;"><a href="/yourpaginationpage.php?paramsfordataonnextpage=&page=<?=$j?>"><?=$j?></a></li>


                   <?}}?>
</div>
</body>
...
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple and clean example to paginate an array, working and tested  OK :)

```
function PaginateArray($input, $page, $show_per_page) {

  $page = $page < 1 ? 1 : $page;

  $start = ($page - 1) * ($show_per_page);
  $offset = $show_per_page;

  $outArray = array_slice($input, $start, $offset);

  var_export($outArray);
 }

  $input =   array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20");

  //page 1
  PaginateArray($input, 1, 3);//inputs: array, page, records per page
 /*
  array (
   0 => '1',
   1 => '2',
   2 => '3',
 )
  */

  //page 2
  PaginateArray($input, 2, 3);//inputs: array, page, records per page
 /*
 array (
  0 => '4',
  1 => '5',
  2 => '6',
)
 */
```