# MYSQL query load data by section as in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, limit

When I run this query on phpmyadmin

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `product_stock` 
WHERE  `product_warehouse_id` =5
LIMIT 100000
```

it loads the data by section 50 by 50 till its stops. But when i do it in a normal php page it takes a while to load and sometimes i get server error. How can I aproach something similar to the way phpmyadmin loads the result?

Comment: add paging like limit 0 50 for page one and then 51 100 for page two and so on

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm
this is tutorial how to add paging on mysql long queries.

Comment: I dont want paging I want all the data to be shown in one page but load it by 50 then add another 50 then add another 50 till it gets to the last number.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL `LIMIT` takes a couple of possible arguments. A single value specifies to return all of those results to the caller. If you pass two values:

```
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Then you're passing the start row and the page size. The 10000 in your example is really just a short form for:

```
LIMIT 0, 10000
```

See the MySQL help documents on [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) for some more detail.

Comment: then if i do a while with the query LIMIT 0, 50 then LIMIT 50, 100 and son on it will add all the tables in the same page?

Comment: @bmacuer - Note the arguments are start row and *page size* so if your second is 50, 100 then you'll retrieve 100 rows on the second call, not 50.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend if you're not going to use all data for all columns, do not use:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 1 AND fieldkey = 'value'
```

If the data size is very large,  causes performance problems in Mysql.

Use:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM tablename WHERE 1 AND fieldkey = 'value'
```

In the SELECT statement, use comma separated names of the columns you want to display, this will help you the server to respond faster without problems and you can paginate through the results easyly.

Also verify that the data on "fieldkey" are indexed, this helps to the query to work faster.

You can paginate the results of your query with something like this:

[php- Paginate data from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595404/php-paginate-data-from-array)

Comment: I understand what you are saying about fields and its a good point, but as I said I need to load the data all in the same page.  Below I responded with the answer I need it.  thanks

Comment: you need to use ajax. same concept but you will get first page then, when user will hit more you will send ajax request to server for next 50 records and you will append on same page then more and more. you can ever use when html table reach @ bottom append more records using ajax check jQuery ajax

Comment: @m-farhan please refer to my own answer on the bottom and you will se no need for ajax.

Comment: @JosephCollins please check my own answer/solution I posted. No need for ajax. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wanted I had to do it with logic at the end it works, below the sample code:

```
while ($limit <= 1000){

    $q1 = "SELECT * 
            FROM  product_stock
            WHERE  product_warehouse_id = 5 
            LIMIT $start, $limit";

    $r1 = mysql_query($q1) or die(mysql_error());

    while($stock_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($r1)){

        echo $stock_info[product_stock_id]."<br />";

    }

    $start = $limit + 1;
    $limit += 50;

}
```

Comment: Great it works for you. how ever I didn't under stand logic it make a new connection to mysql every time you need to get data. Not great approach but good luck.

Comment: You're still not understanding how the LIMIT works and this returns 50, then 100, 150 ... 900, 950, 1000 rows as you go. In addition, your algorithm is good until your data exceeds the sum of that sequence because it's inherently self-limiting (10500 rows).

Comment: You're right @JohnCavan do you have any sugestion on how may I fix the code.

Comment: Change your loop to look at DB response, understand how limits work as I described and linked to, and read up on using [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in PHP.