# Class 'FT_WP_Table' not found

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a WP plugin and I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'FT_WP_Table' not found in
>   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/frequent-traveler/frequent-traveler.php
>   on line 90

This is what I did in my code:

```
add_action('init', 'uploadFileImportCSV');

function uploadFileImportCSV()
{
    $wp_error = true;
    global $wpdb;
    $nonce = isset($_POST['_wpnonce']) ? $_POST['_wpnonce'] : null;

    if (!class_exists('WP_List_Table')) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );

        class FT_WP_Table extends WP_List_Table
        {
            .....
        }

    }

}
```

Should I get out the class from `uploadFileImportCSV()` method? Where is my error?

Comment: **Fatal error: Class 'FT_WP_Table' not found** means exactly what it says

Comment: @Dagon and how exactly that help me?

Comment: What's in line 90? I would take the class definition out of there and move it into it's own file. If you need to test your class, you don't want to have it buried under a ton of extra stuff and hooks. Autoloading might also be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the `init` hook do to some `WP_List_Table` stuff? This hook is also executed on the frontend, for each page load.

Comment: @birgire I'm not a WP expert and this is my first plugin really I don't know where to write that class since my plugin only have two files `frequent-traveler.php` that holds all the logic and `ft_admin.php` which holds some view stuff. Could you help me to write this on the right way?

Comment: You're not making it easy on yourself starting with the `WP_List_Table` in your first plugin ;-) I guess you could search for the `spl_autoload_register()` function and see how it's used, then check out the WordPress plugin boilerplates out there, and the `WP_List_Table` tutorials. Then maybe skim through the code of some of the great oo plugins out there.

Comment: @birgire believe me when I say that I check a lot of plugin but since WP API is new to me (I know how to program using Laravel, Symfony, CodeIgniter and know POO in PHP but WP is totally new) it's hard to start. I use WP_List_Table since it's a cool choice for display a table data but this isn't the problem, the problem I'm having is organizing and structuring the plugin content. The basic steps on the plugin should be: upload a CSV file, read the content, import to WP table, compare file content with User meta data and set some values, display the inserted content, all this is already done

Comment: @birgire but I think it's ugly, can I share the code in pastie with your and get some help? Could you help me?

Comment: You could leave the pastie, but I would have to take a look after the weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for `WP_List_Table` and declare the class at the root of the plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Test
 */

if( is_admin() && !class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) )
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );

class FT_WP_Table extends WP_List_Table
{
    // etc
}
```

Here's a [full example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18933069/1287812).