# How To Display WP_List_Tables on frontend page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**CURRENT ISSUE:**
I have been able to successfully create a variety of table Lists from my WP's sql database within the Dashboard admin area as well as create plugins utilizing WP_LIST_TABLE however am running into difficulty ON how I can display the same table on the frontend of my website using a shortcode. Normally I would add something like:

```
 add_shortcode('joblist', 'Job_List_Plugin');
```

However on this occasion it does not seem to be working. page not producing the table, instead you just see the shortcode you added to the page so in this case [joblist]

**QUESTION:**
How would I add a shortcode element to the following code that would allow me to display this table on a front end page for logged in visitors to see? Examples/Snippets would be appreciated.

```
 if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
 }

 class Job_List extends WP_List_Table {

    /** Class constructor */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct( [
            'singular' => __( 'Custom List', 'red' ), //singular name of the listed records
            'plural'   => __( 'Custom Lists', 'red' ), //plural name of the listed records
            'ajax'     => false //does this table support ajax?
        ] );
    }


    /**
     * Retrieve members data from the database
     *
     * @param int $per_page
     * @param int $page_number
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function get_jobs( $per_page = 10, $page_number = 1 ) {

        global $wpdb;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM custom_table ORDER BY PrintOrder";

        if( ! empty( $_REQUEST['s'] ) ){
         $search = esc_sql( $_REQUEST['s'] );
    $query .= " WHERE Description LIKE '%{$search}%'";
    }

        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['orderby'] ) ) {
            $query .= ' ORDER BY ' . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['orderby'] );
            $query .= ! empty( $_REQUEST['order'] ) ? ' ' . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['order'] ) : ' ASC';
        }

        $query .= " LIMIT $per_page";
        $query .= ' OFFSET ' . ( $page_number - 1 ) * $per_page;

        $result = $wpdb->get_results( $query, 'ARRAY_A' );

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the count of records in the database.
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    public static function record_count() {
        global $wpdb;

        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM custom_table";
        if( ! empty( $_REQUEST['s'] ) ){
         $search = esc_sql( $_REQUEST['s'] );
         $query .= " WHERE Description LIKE '%{$search}%'";
        }
        return $wpdb->get_var( $query );
    }

    /** Text displayed when no member data is available */
    public function no_items() {
        _e( 'There is nothing display at this time.', 'red' );
    }

    /**
     * Render a column when no column specific method exist.
     *
     * @param array $item
     * @param string $column_name
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function column_default( $item, $column_name ) {
        switch ( $column_name ) {
        case 'Description':
        case 'Class':
        case 'EmpName':
        case 'StartTime':
            return $item[ $column_name ];
        default:
            return print_r( $item, true ); //Show the whole array for troubleshooting purposes
    }
}


/**
 *  Associative array of columns
 *
 * @return array
 */
function get_columns() {
    $columns = [
        'Description' => __( 'Classification', 'red' ),
        'Class'    => __( 'Class', 'red' ),
        'EmpName'    => __( 'Employer Name', 'red' ),
        'StartTime'    => __( 'Start Time', 'red' )
    ];

    return $columns;
}


/**
 * Columns to make sortable.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function get_sortable_columns() {
    $sortable_columns = array(
        'Description' => array( 'Classification', true ),
        'Class' => array ( 'Class', true)
    );

    return $sortable_columns;
}
/**
 * Handles data query and filter, sorting, and pagination.
 */
public function prepare_items() {

    $this->_column_headers = $this->get_column_info();

    /** Process bulk action */
    $this->process_bulk_action();

    $per_page     = $this->get_items_per_page( 'jobs_per_page', 7 );
    $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();
    $total_items  = self::record_count();

    $this->set_pagination_args( [
        'total_items' => $total_items, //calculate the total number of items
        'per_page'    => $per_page //determine how many items to show on a page
    ] );

    $this->items = self::get_jobs( $per_page, $current_page );
}




 }

 class Job_List_Plugin {

// class instance
static $instance;

// joblist WP_List_Table object
public $joblist_obj;

// class constructor
public function __construct() {
   add_filter( 'set-screen-option', [ __CLASS__, 'set_screen' ], 10, 3 );
   add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $this, 'plugin_menu' ] );
}


public static function set_screen( $status, $option, $value ) {
    return $value;
}

public function plugin_menu() {

    $hook = add_menu_page(
        'Job List',
        'Job List',
        'manage_options',
        'joblist_viewer',
        [ $this, 'plugin_settings_page' ]
    );

    add_action( "load-$hook", [ $this, 'screen_option' ] );

}


/**
 * Plugin page
 */
public function plugin_settings_page() {
    ?>
    <style>
      table {display: block;overflow-x: scroll;}
      th {min-width:100px;font-size:10px;}
      p.search-box {float:none;}
      #post-body-content {width:98%;}
    </style>
        <h2>IBEW 353 Member Management Portal</h2>
        <p>To locate a specific Member enter their Card Number in the search field provided.</p>
                <div id="post-body-content">
                    <div class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable">
                        <form method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="page" value="joblist_viewer" />
                            <?php
                            $this->joblist_obj->prepare_items();
                            $this->joblist_obj->search_box('Search', 'search');
                            $this->joblist_obj->display(); ?>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <br class="clear">
<?php
}

/**
 * Screen options
 */
public function screen_option() {

    $option = 'per_page';
    $args   = [
        'label'   => 'Jobs Per Page:',
        'default' => 5,
        'option'  => 'jobs_per_page'
    ];

    add_screen_option( $option, $args );

    $this->joblist_obj = new Job_List();
}


/** Singleton instance */
public static function get_instance() {
    if ( ! isset( self::$instance ) ) {
        self::$instance = new self();
    }

    return self::$instance;
}

 }

 add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function () {
    Job_List_Plugin::get_instance();
 } );
```

**UPDATE**
With the help from @Jared Chu I was able to get a bit of headway however am now getting an error. But at least I am seeing the shortcode beginning to work.

Here is what I edited.

line 203 (class construct) I added

```
// class constructor
public function __construct() {
   add_filter( 'set-screen-option', [ __CLASS__, 'set_screen' ], 10, 3 );
   add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $this, 'plugin_menu' ] );
   add_shortcode('joblist', [ $this, 'plugin_settings_page' ] ); // Added shortcode as per suggestion from @Jared Chu
}
```

The public function "plugin_settings_page" contains this code

```
 /**
 * Plugin page
 */
public function plugin_settings_page() {
    ?>
    <style>
      table {display: block;overflow-x: scroll;}
      th {min-width:100px;font-size:10px;}
      p.search-box {float:none;}
      #post-body-content {width:98%;}
    </style>
        <h2>IBEW 353 Member Management Portal</h2>
        <p>To locate a specific Member enter their Card Number in the search field provided.</p>
                <div id="post-body-content">
                    <div class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable">
                        <form method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="page" value="joblist_viewer" />
                            <?php
                            $this->joblist_obj->prepare_items();
                            $this->joblist_obj->search_box('Search', 'search');
                            $this->joblist_obj->display(); ?>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <br class="clear">
<?php
}
```

however when I view the page I dropped the shortcode into I get the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare_items() on null in C:\wamp64\www\dev1\wp-content\plugins\Job-List-Plugin\index.php on line 249

Comment: Are you getting error messages? Please describe it better.

Comment: page not producing the table, instead you just see the shortcode you added to the page so in this case [joblist] updated question to reflect.

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question but did you put this in functions.php?

Comment: no, I have successfully created a plugin which works in the dashboard but am wanting to also display it now in the frontend of my website and having difficulty. No dumb questions. only dumb answers :) hope mine wasn't lol

Comment: Ha, that's fine, all part of the process. Is there something in your plugin maybe that's preventing it from being rendered on the front end?

Comment: i think its more i am having trouble figuring out where to tie it in. I have changed capabilities to "read" but same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_shortcode('joblist', 'Job_List_Plugin');` is not correct.

`add_shortcode` number two ref variable must be a function:

```
# 1. Standard usage
add_shortcode('shortcode_name', 'shortcode_func');

function shortcode_func()
{
 // Contents of this function will execute when the blogger
// uses the [shortcode_name] shortcode.
}

# 2. With PHP 5.3, we can pass an anonymous function.
add_shortcode('shortcode_name', function() {
   // Contents of this function will execute when the blogger
  // uses the [shortcode_name] shortcode.
});

#3. Within a class
class YourPluginClass {
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_shortcode('your_short_code_name', array($this, 'shortcode'));
    }

    public function shortcode()
    {
           // Contents of this function will execute when the blogger
          // uses the [shortcode_name] shortcode.
    }
}
```

So, in your case we will use the #3.

Comment: Hi @Jared Chu, thanks for the assist, I have added an update to my question and hoping you can shine a bit further light on this question. thanks.

Comment: The problem that `joblist_obj` is null, so can you try to put `$this->joblist_obj = new Job_List();` above the add_shortcode line?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function convert_to_screen() when I add that in a new row above the add shortcode line.

Comment: I think that is your class problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867316/call-to-undefined-function-convert-to-screen

Comment: marked you as the right answer as if you didn't give me the insight it would have never worked, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I have learned a lot since this post. Sorry I forgot to mark it.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue myself when attempting to display a WP_List_Table in frontend. I already had a correctly defined shortcode and rendered my menupage in admin outside of the class. Still, I got this error when using the shortcode to render my list in frontend.

After two days of researching and googling I finally figured it out. I needed to require additional classes for it to work in frontend. My guess is that these classes are included in wp-admin mode but not in frontend mode so that is why we need to require them in our child class.

I found my answer here from someone asking for something unrelated but had the correct code I needed: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/350839/wp-list-table-in-frontend-how-to-style-with-bootstrap4

These are the classes and files you need to include:

```
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-screen.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/template.php');
```

Even though this question already has an answer, I will post this here if anyone else is having the same problem.

EDIT: forgot to add how I display the table in frontend. I simply create a new instance of the class in the page-template where I need to render the table. Like so:

```
 <main id="dashboard content">
   <?php
   $list = new LB_WP_Table();
   ?>
 </main>
```

I've used the code from this answer as a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18933069

Here is my full code as of right now:

```
  if( !class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) )
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );


  require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-screen.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/template.php');

class LB_WP_Table extends WP_List_Table {
private $order;
private $orderby;
private $posts_per_page = 5;

public function __construct() {
    parent:: __construct( array(
        'singular' => 'table example',
        'plural'   => 'table examples',
        'ajax'     => true
    ) );

    add_filter( 'get_list_instance', [$this, 'get_instance']);
    add_shortcode('render_list', array($this, 'render_list_table'));
    $this->set_order();
    $this->set_orderby();
    $this->prepare_items();
    $this->display();

}


public function get_instance(){
  return $this;
}

public function render_list_table(){
  $this->set_order();
  $this->set_orderby();
  $this->prepare_items();
  $this->display();
}

private function get_sql_results()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $args = array( 'ID', 'post_title', 'post_date', 'post_content', 'post_type' );
    $sql_select = implode( ', ', $args );
    $sql_results = $wpdb->get_results("
            SELECT $sql_select
                FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE post_status = 'publish'
            ORDER BY $this->orderby $this->order "
    );
    return $sql_results;
}

public function set_order()
{
    $order = 'DESC';
    if ( isset( $_GET['order'] ) AND $_GET['order'] )
        $order = $_GET['order'];
    $this->order = esc_sql( $order );
}

public function set_orderby()
{
    $orderby = 'post_date';
    if ( isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) AND $_GET['orderby'] )
        $orderby = $_GET['orderby'];
    $this->orderby = esc_sql( $orderby );
}

/**
 * @see WP_List_Table::ajax_user_can()
 */
public function ajax_user_can()
{
    return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
}

/**
 * @see WP_List_Table::no_items()
 */
public function no_items()
{
    _e( 'No posts found.' );
}

/**
 * @see WP_List_Table::get_views()
 */
public function get_views()
{
    return array();
}

/**
 * @see WP_List_Table::get_columns()
 */
public function get_columns()
{
    $columns = array(
        'ID'         => __( 'ID' ),
        'post_title' => __( 'Title' ),
        'post_date'  => __( 'Date' ),
        'post_type'  => __( 'Type' )
    );
    return $columns;
}

/**
 * @see WP_List_Table::get_sortable_columns()
 */
public function get_sortable_columns()
{
    $sortable = array(
        'ID'         => array( 'ID', true ),
        'post_title' => array( 'post_title', true ),
        'post_date'  => array( 'post_date', true )
    );
    return $sortable;
}

/**
 * Prepare data for display
 * @see WP_List_Table::prepare_items()
 */
public function prepare_items()
{
    $columns  = $this->get_columns();
    $hidden   = array();
    $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();
    $this->_column_headers = array(
        $columns,
        $hidden,
        $sortable
    );

    // SQL results
    $posts = $this->get_sql_results();
    empty( $posts ) AND $posts = array();

    # >>>> Pagination
    $per_page     = $this->posts_per_page;
    $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();
    $total_items  = count( $posts );
    $this->set_pagination_args( array (
        'total_items' => $total_items,
        'per_page'    => $per_page,
        'total_pages' => ceil( $total_items / $per_page )
    ) );
    $last_post = $current_page * $per_page;
    $first_post = $last_post - $per_page + 1;
    $last_post > $total_items AND $last_post = $total_items;

    // Setup the range of keys/indizes that contain
    // the posts on the currently displayed page(d).
    // Flip keys with values as the range outputs the range in the values.
    $range = array_flip( range( $first_post - 1, $last_post - 1, 1 ) );

    // Filter out the posts we're not displaying on the current page.
    $posts_array = array_intersect_key( $posts, $range );
    # <<<< Pagination

    // Prepare the data
    $permalink = __( 'Edit:' );
    foreach ( $posts_array as $key => $post )
    {
        $link     = get_edit_post_link( $post->ID );
        $no_title = __( 'No title set' );
        $title    = ! $post->post_title ? "<em>{$no_title}</em>" : $post->post_title;
        $posts[ $key ]->post_title = "<a title='{$permalink} {$title}' href='{$link}'>{$title}</a>";
    }
    $this->items = $posts_array;
}

/**
 * A single column
 */
public function column_default( $item, $column_name )
{
    return $item->$column_name;
}

/**
 * Override of table nav to avoid breaking with bulk actions & according nonce field
 */
public function display_tablenav( $which ) {
    ?>
    <div class="tablenav <?php echo esc_attr( $which ); ?>">
        <!--
        <div class="alignleft actions">
            <?php # $this->bulk_actions( $which ); ?>
        </div>
         -->
        <?php
        $this->extra_tablenav( $which );
        $this->pagination( $which );
        ?>
        <br class="clear" />
    </div>
    <?php
}

/**
 * Disables the views for 'side' context as there's not enough free space in the UI
 * Only displays them on screen/browser refresh. Else we'd have to do this via an AJAX DB update.
 *
 * @see WP_List_Table::extra_tablenav()
 */
public function extra_tablenav( $which )
{
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    $views = $this->get_views();
    if ( empty( $views ) )
        return;

    $this->views();
}
} // class

if (!is_admin()){ // Only do this in frontend
  $list = new LB_WP_Table(); 
}


add_action('admin_menu', function()
{
    add_menu_page(
        'TE',
        '<span style="color:#e57300;">Table Example</span>',
        'edit_pages',
        'table-example',
        function() {
            echo '<div class="wrap">';
            screen_icon('edit');
            echo '<h2>Table Example</h2>';
            new LB_WP_Table();
            echo '</div>';
        },
    'http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/favicon.ico',
        1  // create before Dashboard menu item
    );
});
```