# Wordpress MYSQL Error

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb

Can someone help me fix the error below?

**ERROR**

> [Fri Mar 04 23:37:59.682275 2016] [:error] [pid 9392] [client
>   222.127.94.8:45468] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10 for query
>   SELECT DISTINCT ID, post_title, post_password, comment_ID,\n
>   comment_post_ID, comment_author, comment_author_email,
>   comment_date_gmt, comment_approved,\n
>   comment_type,comment_author_url,\n SUBSTRING(comment_content,1,110) AS
>   com_excerpt\n FROM wp_comments\n LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_posts ON
>   (wp_comments.comment_post_ID =\n wp_posts.ID)\n WHERE comment_approved
>   = '1' AND comment_type = '' AND\n post_password = ''\n ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC LIMIT made by require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   include('/themes/theme/404.php'), dynamic_sidebar,
>   call_user_func_array, WP_Widget->display_callback, Comments->widget,
>   referer:

Code in Theme:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ID, post_title, post_password, comment_ID,
comment_post_ID, comment_author, comment_author_email, comment_date_gmt, comment_approved,
comment_type,comment_author_url,
SUBSTRING(comment_content,1,100) AS com_excerpt
FROM $wpdb->comments
LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON ($wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID =
$wpdb->posts.ID)
WHERE comment_approved = '1' AND comment_type = '' AND
post_password = ''
ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC LIMIT ".$comment_posts;

$comments = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
$output = $pre_HTML;

foreach ($comments as $comment) {
```

What do i need to replace in the CODE above to fix the error?

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: `$wpdb->` all seem like they don't belong from a pure SQL standpoint.  But maybe WordPress does something different with SQL than I'm aware.  I'm also unsure what `.$comment_Posts;` is hoping to achieve.

Comment: thanks for your input sir

Comment: `$comment_posts`  seems to be null

Comment: update: due to this error when i update from my dashboard (any settings) it takes upto 5mins or sometimes it will display the connection was reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got similar type of problem while using order by and limit in wordpress query.i rewrite query shown in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322266/add-pagination-in-wordpress-admin-in-my-own-customized-plugin). i think wordpress have different structure while appending variable.try it.