# how to add pagination in wordpress admin page(Reservation) and how can print as pdf my reservation

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to display pagination in one of my page of plugin ,created by me..

I am grateful if someone can help
i want pagination in back end(in admin) not in front end, and print reservation as pdf.
this my function how can i add pagination and print as pdf?

thank you

```
function friday_reservations(){ 

<div class="wrap">
    <h1>Reservations</h1>
    <table class="wp-list-table widefat striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="manage-column">ID</th>
                <th class="manage-column">Gebet</th>
                <th class="manage-column">Genre</th>
                <th class="manage-column">Name</th>
                <th class="manage-column">Last Name</th>
                <th class="manage-column">E-mail</th>
                <th class="manage-column">Phone</th>
                <th class="manage-column">Number</th>
                <th class="manage-column">Delete</th>
            
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            global $wpdb;
            $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'fridyreservation';
            $reservations = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table", ARRAY_A);
           
            foreach($reservations as $reservation): ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $reservation['id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $reservation['predigt']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $reservation['genre']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $reservation['fname']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $reservation['lname']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $reservation['email']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $reservation['phone']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $reservation['pnumber']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="remove_reservation" data-reservation="<?php echo $reservation['id']; ?>">Remove</a>
                    </td>
                
                </tr>


            <?php endforeach;
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

this part is the database function :

```
function friday_reservation_database(){
global $wpdb;

global $friday_reservation_db_version;
$friday_reservation_db_version = "1.1";

$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'fridyreservation';
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

//SQL Statement
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table(
    id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    predigt varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    genre varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    fname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    lname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(50) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    phone varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    pnumber varchar(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)

)$charset_collate; ";

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
dbDelta( $sql);
```

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'friday_reservation_database');

Answer (score 0):

the solution was hier

[Add pagination in wordpress admin in my own customized plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322266/add-pagination-in-wordpress-admin-in-my-own-customized-plugin)

```
$pagenum = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? absint( $_GET['pagenum'] ) : 1;
$limit = 10; // number of rows in page
$offset = ( $pagenum - 1 ) * $limit;
$total = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table_name" ``);
$num_of_pages = ceil( $total / $limit );``
$entries = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table_name LIMIT $offset, $limit" );
$page_links = paginate_links( array(
'base' => add_query_arg( 'pagenum', '%#%' ),
'format' => '',
'prev_text' => __( '&laquo;', 'text-domain' ),
'next_text' => __( '&raquo;', 'text-domain' ),
'total' => $num_of_pages,
'current' => $pagenum
) );

if ( $page_links ) {
echo '<div class="tablenav"><div class="tablenav-pages" style="margin: 1em 0">' . $page_links . '</div></div>';
}
```

thats all